# How to Show Maximum Frequency Value from a groupBy Table

Tags: python

```
  Customer Name       Segment     Discount    Profit    
1   Jane Waco       Corporate       0.2     1906.4850   
2   Joseph Holt     Consumer        0.4     -1862.3124  
3   Greg Maxwell    Corporate       0.0     83.2810 
4   Thomas Boland   Corporate       0.0     517.4793    
5   Sue Ann Reed    Consumer        0.2     341.9940    
6   Karen Ferguson  Home Office     0.2     363.9048    
7   Joel Eaton      Consumer        0.3     -350.4900   
8   Nora Preis      Consumer        0.2     135.4068
```

In Jane Waco transaction, she has made many purchases. Each purchases have a different amount of discounts. How to show the most frequent amount of discount shown on her purchase? In this set of data of coding that i have made, the discount column only shows the highest but i want the most frequent

```
   from collections import Counter
   L = data["Discount"]
   data.groupby('Customer Name')['Discount'].nunique()
   maxi = Counter(data['Discount']).most_common(1)
   data.iloc[1:24,[6,7,maxi,21,24,25]]
```

Discount is index 20 but i dont know how to show the most frequent discount of Jane Waco received

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly...
It boils down to a question of how to get the most common item in a list.

```
l = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 11, 12]
dic = dict([(str(i), 0) for i in l])
for value in l:
    dic[str(value)] += 1

values = dic.items()
values.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

most_common = values[-1][0]
```